# Java DataStream alignment

Tags: java

I have to do the following exercise. Can someone please explain why the 3 bits in the example are misaligned?

```
/*
 * A data stream contains a binary stream of data in little endian byte format.
 *
 * The binary data can be mis-aligned to byte boundaries.
 * In order to indicate alignment to the consumer, a periodic alignment 
 * synchronisation sequence is output.
 * The alignment sequence is defined as 4 bytes of 0x00 followed by a byte of 0x80.
 *
 * For example, the following stream is mis-aligned by 3 bits and has an alignment sequence followed by 
 * the byte values 0x01,0x02,0x03
 *
 * 0x65, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x08, 0x10, 0x18
 *
 * The sequence ends when there's not enough bits left to fill a byte
 *
 */
```

Moreover, this is the interface that has to be implemented

```
 interface RawDataStream{

/*
 * Reads raw data from a stream
 *
 * @param buffer to store read bytes in
 * @param num_bytes number of bytes to read from the stream into the buffer
 * 
 * @return number of bytes read from stream into buffer
 *        -1 no data in stream
 *        -2 End of stream
 */

 int readBytes(char[] buffer, int num_bytes);
 }
```

What is the best way to verify the alignment sequence?